# Why should we not write or read ref.current during rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

## Problem

I have a memoised component to render list items that takes in a callback function (onClick handler). This callback is dependent on some state variables (and manipulating them), but to not unnecessary rerender all items in the list, I would like to avoid adding the state variable in the dependency list of the callback function.

### Example

In the following example, the selection state is added to the dependency list of the onClick callback, hence it will rerender all items, instead of only the item that was clicked.

```
const Item = React.memo(
  ({ id, selected, onClick }: { id: string; selected: boolean; onClick: (id: string) => void }) => {
    return (
      <li style={{ fontWeight: selected ? 'bold' : 'normal' }} onClick={() => onClick(id)}>
        {id}
      </li>
    );
  }
);

const List = ({ items, onSelect }: { items: string[]; onSelectionChange: (selection: string[]) => void }) => {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const onClick = useCallback(
    (id: string) => {
      const newSelection = selection.includes(id) ? selection.filter(i => i !== id) : [...selection, id];
      onSelect(newSelection);
      setSelection(newSelection);
    },
    [selection, onSelect] // <= want to avoid selection state in the dependency list
  );

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item key={item} id={item} selected={selection.includes(item)} onClick={onClick} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

### Proposed solution by React.dev

The proposed solution by [React.dev](https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#are-you-reading-some-state-to-calculate-the-next-state) is to use an updater function to change the selection state.

The problem with this approach is that side effects (like calling another callback `onSelect`) are not allowed in this updater function.

## Solution (mine)

To fix the above problem I came up with the following alternative for the useState hook:

```
export function useStableState<S>(
  initialState: S
): [state: S, setState: (next: S | ((state: S) => S)) => void, getState: () => S] {
  const [, rerender] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0); // dummy reducer to create a rerender function
  const state = useRef(initialState);
  const setState = useCallback((next: S | ((state: S) => S)) => {
    const nextState = typeof next === 'function' ? next(state.current) : next;
    if (!Object.is(state.current, nextState)) {
      state.current = nextState;
      rerender();
    }
  }, []);
  const getState = useCallback(() => state.current, []);
  return [state.current, setState, getState];
}
```

Which is a drop-in replacement for the regular `useState` hook.
But additionally it provides a stable `getState` function to gather state without losing memoisation and unlike the regular `useState` hook, side effects are allowed in the updater function.

So with this solution we can change the above List component into.

```
const List = ({ items, onSelect }: { items: string[]; onSelect: (selection: string[]) => void }) => {
  const [selection, setSelection, getSelection] = useStableState<string[]>([]);

  const onClick = useCallback(
    (id: string) => {
      const selection = getSelection();
      const newSelection = selection.includes(id) ? selection.filter(i => i !== id) : [...selection, id];
      onSelect(newSelection);
      setSelection(newSelection);
    },
    [setSelection, getSelection, onSelect] // all stable function, so onClick will be stable as well
  );

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item key={item} id={item} selected={selection.includes(item)} onClick={onClick} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

## Question

Although the above solution works as far as I tested it, are there any tricky issues / pitfalls?

One thing is, that I read the ref.current during rendering, which is not allowed according to [React.dev docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#caveats).
Can someone explain why this is not allowed or what problems it will cause?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [, rerender] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0); // dummy reducer
```

This is obviously a hack. If you remove it , it won't work.

Code example and quote from [React docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#caveats):

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  let ref = useRef(0);

  function handleClick() {
    ref.current = ref.current + 1;
    alert('You clicked ' + ref.current + ' times!');
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me!
    </button>
  );
}
```

> If you show {ref.current} in the JSX, the number won’t update on
> click. This is because setting ref.current does not trigger a
> re-render. Information that’s used for rendering should be state
> instead.

The main take away is the "setting ref.current does not trigger a re-render. "

So to answer your question:

> Can someone explain why this is not allowed or what problems it will cause?

The problem is that your UI will go out of sync as React does not update the UI based on the changes of `ref.current`.

Comment: that's why I 'manually' trigger a rerender when necessary with the dummy reducer.

I agree it's somewhat 'hacky' but this hack was proposed by React itself: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate